# create a mass of connections on client side by twisted

Tags: twisted

I use twisted to do a test job for a server. I need create a lot of connections connect to the server. This is my code:

```
class Account(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connection made"
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "connection Lost. reason: ", reason
    def createAccount(self, name):
        self.transport.write(...)
        print "create account: ", name

class AccountFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Account()

def accountCreate(p, i):
    print "begin create"
    p.createAccount(NAME_PREFIX+str(i))

def onError(err):
    return 'error: ', err

c = 0
while c < 100: 
    accountPoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, server_ip, port)
    accountConn = accountPoint.connect(AccountFactory())

    accountConn.addCallback(accountCreate, c)
    accountConn.addErrback(onError)
    c += 1

reactor.run()
```

If server and client located in same LAN, there is no problem, all of 100 "create account: xxx" will printed. But when I put server on a remote address(internet), the client only prints near 50% number of "create account: xxx". `onError` doesn't fire.

The log is:

```
2014-07-29 15:57:06+0800 [Uninitialized] connection made
2014-07-29 15:57:06+0800 [Uninitialized] begin create
2014-07-29 15:57:06+0800 [Uninitialized] create account: xxx
repeat 60 times
2014-07-29 15:57:17+0800 [Uninitialized] Stopping factory <__main__.AccountFactory instance at xxx>
repeat 40 times
```

Some callback failed to be calling, even the connection haven't be made. The only different is the latency between server and client.

The most interested thing is the duration between first success log and first "Stopping factory" log is exactly 20 seconds(I try this many times). But I am sure this is not caused by timeout because `TCP4ClientEndpoint` default timeout is 30 seconds.

And the log time stamp is also abnormal, the log time stamp is in bundle, for example: 10 logs are 2014-07-29 17:25:09, 20 logs are 2014-07-29 17:25:15. If the connection made in async manner, the time stamp should be random enough. It should not gather together: made 10 connections at time point a, made another 20 at time point a+15sec. Or log utility problem?

**Revised:**
I think this is bug of twisted. The reason of "Stopping" is timeout. When I run this in linux, the time duration between first log and first stopping is timeout seconds I passed into `TCP4ClientEndpoint`, but under windows whatever I set the timeout seconds, the duration always 21 seconds. I use socket(blocking) to do same thing instead, all is pretty good. So this should be a bug in twisted which involve timeout when making a lot of connections.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added any error handlers to your code, nor have you enabled logging so that unhandled errors will be reported anywhere.

Enable logging, either by calling `twisted.python.log.startLogging` or by writing your code as an `ISeviceMaker` plugin and running it with `twistd`.

And add errbacks to each `Deferred` in your application so you can handle failures from their associate operations.

Comment: I got "[Uninitialized] Stopping factory <__main__.AccountFactory instance at 0x03E76490>" when open log. the number of this kind of log equal to the lack number of "create account" and the accountCreate function haven't been called, what happened?

Comment: Did you add an errback to the `Deferred` to log the error?

Comment: Your errback doesn't log anything.  Instead, it returns a tuple.  Try using `twisted.python.log.err` as your errback instead.

Comment: This works, the output is: "Failure: twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 10060". But I don't know why it will timeout. The connections made by twisted is more slow than blocking socket(5,6 seconds).

Comment: It's hard to compare the performance of your incomplete Twisted-based example to the performance of another unspecified example.

Comment: I mean this is abnormal, it should not so slow and it should not timeout.

Comment: You can keep saying that but without a minimal, self-contained, complete example no one is going to be able to provide you with much help.